# Nestjs, how to load multiple instance of a module

Tags: nestjs

I have a nestjs module x talk to a third party API with configured (baseURL, username, password).

Now in my nestjs I want this module x support different instances of the API (different baseURL, username, password).

How do i instanciate this module x twice, each with different configs. So I can talk to many apis as needed?

I was thinking first dynamically load this module

```
moduleInstance = await import(./x.module);
```

Then, use LazyModuleLoader to load this module x

```
const { ApiModule, Configuration } = moduleInstance
const cmModuleRef = await this.lazyModuleLoader.load(() => ApiModule.forRoot(() => new Configuration({ basePath: config.baseUrl, username: config.userName, password: config.password })));
```

The problem is now LazyModuleLaoder always give me the same module instance. where in my case, I want two instance of module x, each with different configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it would be better to create a client for each of the 3rd party API and specify the connection details in a yaml file e.g.

```js
// config.yaml
services:
  facebook:
    url: https://www.facebook.com/
    username: ${FACEBOOK_USERNAME}
    password: ${FACEBOOK_PASSWORD}
  microsoft:
    url: https://www.microsoft.com/
    username: ${MICROSOFT_USERNAME}
    password: ${MICROSOFT_PASSWORD}
```

```js
// config/configuration.ts

import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import * as yaml from 'js-yaml';
import { join } from 'path';

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'config';
const YAML_CONFIG_FILENAME = `${ENV}.yaml`;

export default () => {
  return yaml.load(
readFileSync(join(__dirname, YAML_CONFIG_FILENAME), 'utf8')
  .replaceAll('${FACEBOOK_USERNAME}', process.env.FACEBOOK_USERNAME)
  .replaceAll('${FACEBOOK_PASSWORD}', process.env.FACEBOOK_PASSWORD)
  .replaceAll('${MICROSOFT_USERNAME}', process.env.MICROSOFT_USERNAME)
  .replaceAll('${MICROSOFT_PASSWORD}', process.env.MICROSOFT_PASSWORD)
  ) as Record<string, any>;
};
```

```js
// nest-cli.json

{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "assets": [{"include": "../config/*.yaml", "outDir": "./dist/config"}]
  }
}
```

```js
// app.module.ts

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot({ load: [configuration] }),],
  // ...
  providers: [MicrosoftClient, FacebookClient],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```js
// facebook.client.ts

@Injectable()
export class FacebookClient {
  private readonly logger: Logger = new Logger(FacebookClient.name);
  private readonly URL: string = this.configService.get<string>('services.facebook.url');
  private readonly USERNAME: string = this.configService.get<string>('services.facebook.username');
  private readonly PASSWORD: string = this.configService.get<string>('services.facebook.password');

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService, private httpService: HttpService) {}

  //...

 }
```

```js
// microsoft.client.ts

@Injectable()
export class MicrosoftClient {
  private readonly logger: Logger = new Logger(MicrosoftClient.name);
  private readonly URL: string = this.configService.get<string>('services.microsoft.url');
  private readonly USERNAME: string = this.configService.get<string>('services.microsoft.username');
  private readonly PASSWORD: string = this.configService.get<string>('services.microsoft.password');

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService, private httpService: HttpService) {}

  //...

 }
```

The NestJS [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration) have further details on how to use the config service

Comment: My problem is that, we don't know how many client before hand. So Admin may come and add a new client (baseURL, username, password). it's the same API, but with different  instances (baseURL). My idea, to dynamically create an module instance using nestjs's LazyModuleLoader, but failed so far.

Comment: You could probably still do that with the code above if you have 1 client and different environment configs with different connection details and usernames and passwords

Comment: yeah, thanks your aproach is indeed a solutin. But the client (Facebook, Microsoft) has too be manually write,. I was trying to generate client code to a module. https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript-nestjs. So maybe I should not use a code-gen for the api, but write it myselft with HttpService?